# Django Updating var on file depending of a model

Tags: python, django-models

I have a file whose contents depends on a model.
Bizarre thing : when updating the model's data, it does not directly reverberate on the variable on that file! I was forced to restart my dev server to have the new data.

As a solution I used 'reload' to reload the module containing the variables in question! I think it's not the good way to do that (reloading after every update) to be able to see the data.

Is there any way to update and see data directly without reloading?.

Here is my code:  http://pastebin.com/97BPqh0L I had a commentary at the reload section

```
# parametres/conf.py


from .models import ConfigApp

if ConfigApp.objects.exists():
     config = ConfigApp.objects.all()[0]
else:     config = None

EMPLOYE_BY_COMPAGNY = config.user_compagnie if config else 7

ANNONCES_LIFETIMES = config.annonce_days if config else None

IMAGE_SIZE = config.taille_image*1024 if config else 102400

#####################################################"

# compte/admin.py


from societe.models import Compagnie
from .forms import EmployeAdminForm,NewEmployeAdminForm
from django.contrib import admin
from django.contrib.auth.models import User,Group
import parametres.conf

class EmployeAdmin(admin.ModelAdmin):
     list_display = ['user','identite','email','societe','is_active']
     list_filter = ('is_active','societe')
     form = NewEmployeAdminForm
     search_fields = ("user__username",)
     user_obj = None

     def has_add_permission(self,request):
          reload( parametres.conf) #here reloading

          if request.user.is_superuser or request.user.groups.filter(name='admin').exists():
                    return True
          elif request.user.groups.filter(name='client').exists():
                    if Gestionnaire.objects.filter(employe__user=request.user,is_active=True).exists():
                         employe = request.user.employe_set.all()[0]
                         if Employe.objects.filter(societe=employe.societe).count() >= parametres.conf.EMPLOYE_BY_COMPAGNY:
                              return False
                         return True
          return False
```

Comment: How about you show some code, buddy? We're all experienced guys here, we can take it.

Comment: Can you post some code to show what you are trying to do?

Comment: how to add the code pretty new here

Answer (score 1):

The only way to solve this is to not use global state in the first place. Create a class that uses properties to pull the data from the appropriate place each time, optionally implementing caching if desired.